# How to properly write a test in jest library for react component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have simple react component for rendering images that looks like that:

```
import { string } from "prop-types"
import * as Styled from "./Image.styled"

const Image = ({ Src, Alt }) => <Styled.Image src={Src} alt={Alt} />

Image.propTypes = {
  Alt: string,
  Src: string,
}

Image.defaultProps = {
  Alt: null,
  Src: null,
}
export default Image
```

for this one I ma trying to write a test to check if src and Alt will render properly.
I tried to write something like that:

```
import { render, screen } from "../../../test-utils"

import Image from "../Image"

const src ="https://images.pexels.com/photos/39317/chihuahua-dog-puppy-cute-39317.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
const alt = "dog"

describe(`Image`, () => {
  it(`renders Image with default properties`, () => {
    render(<Image src={src} alt={alt} />)
    expect(screen.getByText(Image)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

But it fails. Terminal says that it is on the method line, so any idea which one might be better?

Comment: Your test makes no sense. You're not passing the right props and you're using the component to try to select itself _as text_?! Also there's no reason to have defaults for at least the Src prop, certainly not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your test like this (check the casing for properties):

```js
describe('Image', () => {
  it('renders Image with default properties', () => {
    render(<Image Src={src} Alt={alt} />);
    expect(screen.getByAltText(alt)).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```

Check image src:

```js
it('renders Image with default properties', () => {
  render(<Image Src={src} Alt={alt} />);
  expect(screen.getByRole('img')).toHaveAttribute('src', src);
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :)  Also, can you help for the test for SRC? I wrote :  describe("Image", () => {
  it("renders Image with alt text", () => {
    render(<Image Src={src} Alt={alt} />)
    expect(screen.getByRole(src)).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
}) But it fails -,- src is a link of course so can this be a problem?

Comment: @Emilia I have updated my answer. You need to find the image tag and then check the `src`  attribute value if it is as expected. Please check the docs of rect testing library for when to use getByRole and other element finding methods.

Comment: Thank you this works :) I will definitelly do, many thanks